# Chrome. Все масштабированные картинки стали размытые

Tags: google-chrome

В Google Chrome. Все масштабированные картинки стали размытые.
пробовал: перезагрузку, переустановить хром, менять флаги хрома, указать масштабирование в системе 120%, менять частоту экрана, обновлять дрова.

В других браузерах проблемы нет. Началась недавно.

(Если убрать масштабирование через devtools картинка нормально рендерится, стоит 100% масштабирование в самом браузере. Если сменить на 90% или любое другое, все нормально ровно секунду, после чего картинки заменяются мылом)

Chrome 58.0.3029.81 x64
Asus n76v
Win 8 x64,
intel hd graphics 4000,
geforce 740m

Так же второй системой стоит ubuntu-17. (много ковырялся там с дровами, intel там вообще не завелся, только gefroce. может быть как то связано, не знаю)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалось решить запустив программу с выбором gpu geforce. В самой системе стоит не автовыбор, а использовать gpu, а у хрома в программных настройках стояло интегрир. оборудование. Почему на нем не работает конечно странно, но вопрос более не актуален.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо за наводку на идею, что дело в видеокарте...

Chrome 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit)
Win 8

Избавился от такой проблемы с помощью отключения в найстройках Хрома галочки "Использовать аппаратное ускорение".
После перезагрузки Хрома все уменьшенные картинки стали нормального качества.